Operator overloading with generics, multiple abstract classes c++
I'm creating a library that uses a dimension3 as abstract class.
As example:
/// \brief Abstract class to represent 3 dimensions
/// \note This class is not meant to be used directly, but to be inherited by other classes
/// \details This class implements the basic operations for 3 dimensions (+, +=, -, -=, *, *=, /, /=, %, %=, ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=, -, ++, --, <<)
class dimension3 {
protected:
    template<typename T>
    using enable_if_dimension3 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<dimension3, T>>;

public:
    double x{}, y{}, z{};
    
    /// \brief Add a double to a dimension3 (dim3 += n)
    /// \tparam T Type of the dimension3, must be a derived class of dimension3
    /// \param dimension3 Dimension3 containing the result
    /// \param n Value to add
    /// \return A reference to the dimension3 with the result of the addition
    template<typename T, typename = enable_if_dimension3<T>>
    friend const T& operator+=(T& dimension3, double n) noexcept {
        dimension3.x += n;
        dimension3.y += n;
        dimension3.z += n;
        return dimension3;
    }
    virtual void something_virtual() = 0;
}; // class dimension3

This works perfectly fine and I can implement vector3 : public dimension3.
Yet for obvious reasons when I want to add a dimension4 I can't use the same layout:
/// \brief Abstract class to represent 4 dimensions
/// \note This class is not meant to be used directly, but to be inherited by other classes
/// \details This class implements the basic operations for 4 dimensions (+, +=, -, -=, *, *=, /, /=, %, %=, ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=, -, ++, --, <<)
class dimension4 {
protected:
    template<typename T>
    using enable_if_dimension4 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<dimension4, T>>;

public:
    double x{}, y{}, z{}, w{};
    
    /// \brief Add a double to a dimension4 (dim4 += n)
    /// \tparam T Type of the dimension4, must be a derived class of dimension4
    /// \param dimension4 Dimension4 containing the result
    /// \param n Value to add
    /// \return A reference to the dimension4 with the result of the addition
    template<typename T, typename = enable_if_dimension4<T>>
    friend const T& operator+=(T& dimension4, double n) noexcept
    {
        dimension4.x += n;
        dimension4.y += n;
        dimension4.z += n;
        dimension4.w += n;
        return dimension4;
    }
    virtual void something_virtual() = 0;
}; // class dimension4

This isn't going to work because it can't define friend const T& operator+=(T&, double) twice. Are there some easy solutions to this issue?
I've seen people use decltype() and dimension3<T> but I don't really like the second option.
Minimum viable product
class point3 : public dimension3 {
public:
    point3(double x, double y, double z) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
    void something_virtual() override {}
}; // class point3

class point4 : public dimension4 {
public:
    point4(double x, double y, double z, double w)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
        this->w = w;
    }
    void something_virtual() override {}
}; // class point4

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    point3 p3{1, 2, 3};
    point4 p4{1, 2, 3, 4};

    p3 += 1.2;
    p4 += 1.2; // error: No viable operator+= matches arguments of type point4 and double.
}

I suppose this isn't necessary a question about overloading but more about generics.

Since that operator is defined as a friend, you are essentially redefining the same operator multiple times, but the second time with a different default template argument (where the first one then wins out as the actual default, and technically the compiler could probably even give an error at the point of the second declaration). Is there any way you can use C++20 concepts? Because in that case you could actually declare distinct operators.

Why are dimension3 and dimension4 templated in friend const T& operator+=(T& dimension3, double n) noexcept and friend const T& operator+=(T& dimension4, double n) noexcept? If you just remove the template parameters and use the types, there's no problem. Example

giving same name to the class and a local variable is very confusing

Sidenote: These classes are very similar. I'd make it a class template that takes the number of dimensions you want as a template parameter

its not "generics". Java and other languages have generics. Templates in C++ are very different from that.

@TedLyngmo I agree with you there wouldn't be an issue. Yet if I want to add an operator+ that returns a copy of dimension3 I'll be unable to due to the abstract nature.

SFINAE with typename = enable_if_dimension4_t<T> is not overload friendly, prefer enable_if_dimension4_t<T, bool> = true

Do you really need these classes to be abstract and polymorphic? Perhaps you could get away with CRTP.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I do like the new c++23 version of CRTP. I've used to old one where you add a template to dimension3 but you'd be unable to use it for polymorphism, if I'm not incorrect.

Depends on which brand of polymorphism is your cup of tea. I think the new deduced-this can be used exactly like CRTP.

Use requires and concepts if you have the standard version.
If you don't
template<typename T>
using enable_if_dimension3 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<dimension3, T>, bool>;

notice the , bool added.  This template is a SFINAE error if it fails, and a bool if it succeeds.  Yours was a void on success.
Then change +=:
template<typename T,  enable_if_dimension3<T> = true>
friend const T& operator+=(T& dimension3, double n) noexcept

here I swapped using the type value of the dummy template argument to do SFINAE in to using the type of the dummy non-type template argument to do SFINAE in.  (note that =true could be =false or =0 and it wouldn't matter; but =true makes it less confusing to people who don't understand how it works).
The difference is subtle but extremely useful.
Before, you had two different:
template<class,class> operator+=

after my changes, we have exactly one
template<class,bool> operator+=

The other one doesn't exist as its 2nd non-type template argument type is a SFINAE.
This technique doesn't mess with any of the meaninful template arguments or function arguments or return values.  The magic is cobstrained to that one extra non-type template argument.
What more, you can upgrade it to concepts easily.
template<class T> requires BLAH_CONCEPT<T>

or even
template<BLAH_CONCEPT T>

is easy to produce from
template<class T, sfinae_blah_test<T> =true>

and only involves touching the sfinae machinery, making the change more reliable.
Writing a concept is easy.  In this case it is already written.
template<std::derived_from<dimension3> T>
friend T& operator+=(T& t, double d)

...
template<std::derived_from<dimension3> T>
T operator+(T t, double d) {
  t+=d;
  return t;
}

Nice and clean.
We can also go further in the cleanup.  We can use this template parameters to get the derived type of ourselves.  But this is closer to the bleeding edge.

This makes a lot of sense.

Problem is that you have selected wrong way to achieve SFINAE.
As compiler says: https://godbolt.org/z/re7zE6K55
<source>:46:37: error: template parameter redefines default argument
   46 |     template<typename T, typename = enable_if_dimension4<T>>
      |                                     ^
<source>:20:37: note: previous default template argument defined here
   20 |     template<typename T, typename = enable_if_dimension3<T>>
      |                                     ^
<source>:47:21: error: redefinition of 'operator+='
   47 |     friend const T& operator+=(T& dimension4, double n) noexcept
      |                     ^

So problem is ambiguous default type parameter of template operator+=.
Change template to be single type parameter and achive SFINAE by applying it on return type and your code starts to compile:
/// \brief Abstract class to represent 3 dimensions
/// \note This class is not meant to be used directly, but to be inherited by other classes
/// \details This class implements the basic operations for 3 dimensions (+, +=, -, -=, *, *=, /, /=, %, %=, ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=, -, ++, --, <<)
class dimension3 {
protected:
    template<typename T>
    using enable_if_dimension3 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<dimension3, T>, const T&>;

public:
    double x{}, y{}, z{};
    
    /// \brief Add a double to a dimension3 (dim3 += n)
    /// \tparam T Type of the dimension3, must be a derived class of dimension3
    /// \param dimension3 Dimension3 containing the result
    /// \param n Value to add
    /// \return A reference to the dimension3 with the result of the addition
    template<typename T>
    friend auto operator+=(T& dimension3, double n) noexcept -> enable_if_dimension3<T> {
        dimension3.x += n;
        dimension3.y += n;
        dimension3.z += n;
        return dimension3;
    }
    virtual void something_virtual() = 0;
}; // class dimension3

https://godbolt.org/z/EnhEf8aaq
Note that trick with extra template parameter used to achieve SFINAE was invented to have SFINAE in case of constructors which do not have return type.
Disclaimer:
This is a quick fix. It would be better to rename related symbols after my fix.
Final note:
With C++20 you can use concepts and make this much nicer.

Interesting, never knew this was a thing in c++. Thank you very much!
I think restructuring my program will be the way forward but thank you. :D

As I pointed out in a comment, you are redefining the same friend function and I'd revisit the base design of dimension3 and dimension4. These classes have so much in common, without being the same thing, that I would suggest making a class template out of them where a std::size_t template parameter is used to select how many dimensions there should be.
template <std::size_t N>
class dimension {
public:
    // constructor:
    explicit dimension(std::convertible_to<double> auto&&... args)
        : data{static_cast<double>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args))...} {
            static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N, "incorrect number of arguments");
    }

    // access using indices known at compile time:
    template<std::size_t I>
    double& get() {
        static_assert(I < N, "I out of bounds");
        return data[I];
    }
    template<std::size_t I>
    const double& get() const {
        static_assert(I < N, "I out of bounds");
        return data[I];
    }

    // subscript access for values only known at runtime:
    const double& operator[](size_t idx) const { return data[idx]; }
    double& operator[](size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }

    // a virtual member function
    virtual void something_virtual() = 0;

    // add double to self
    dimension& operator+=(double n) noexcept {
        [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
            ((data[I] += n), ...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
        return *this;
    }

    // free operator+ overloads
    friend auto operator+(const std::derived_from<dimension> auto& d, double n) {
        auto rv = d;
        rv += n;
        return rv;
    }
    friend auto operator+(double n, const std::derived_from<dimension> auto& d) {
        return d + n;
    }

private:
    double data[N]; // the dimension data
};  // class dimension

With that, you've got a template for dimension<1> ... dimension<X> ready and the concrete classes could just inherit and implement something_virtual:
class point2 : public dimension<2> {
public:
    using dimension<2>::dimension;
    using dimension<2>::operator=;
    void something_virtual() override {}
};

class point3 : public dimension<3> {
public:
    using dimension<3>::dimension;
    using dimension<3>::operator=;
    void something_virtual() override {}
};

class point4 : public dimension<4> {
public:
    using dimension<4>::dimension;
    using dimension<4>::operator=;
    void something_virtual() override {}
};

Demo
If you keep the virtual member function, you may also want to add a virtual destructor, or else destroying an instance via the base class destructor will not do the right thing.
